# Simplify search for matching values

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with the following columns: `ColA, ColB, ColC, Rate`. All except `Rate` are nullable.

I have 3 parameters - @A, @B and @C, which will always have values.

I would like to find the first row in the table that satisfies most matches. The best match would be where all parameters match.

Currently, I have to write each combination and check matches.

`Select Rate From MyTable Where ColA=@A And ColB=@B And ColC=@C`

If nothing found, then

`Select Rate From MyTable Where ColA=@A And ColB=@B And ColC Is Null`

If nothing found, then

`Select Rate From MyTable Where ColA=@A And ColB Is Null And ColC=@C`

and so on... e.g.

`Select Rate From MyTable Where ColA Is Null And ColB=@B And ColC=@C`

`Select Rate From MyTable Where ColA Is Null And ColB=@B And ColC Is Null`

`Select Rate From MyTable Where ColA Is Null And ColB Is Null And ColC=@C;`

`Select Rate From MyTable Where ColA Is Null And ColB Is Null And ColC Is Null;`

Now, I need to add a fourth column `ColD`. Is there any faster way to match rows other than trying all combinations?

Answer (score 2):

When you say faster, I assume you mean faster to write, because if thjos columns are indexed then almost any option is going to be slower than doing point lookups on indexes.

If I understand you correctly, if there is a value in a column then it **must** match it's parameter.

Here is one option. Basically we order the results by the number of non null columns.

```
Select TOP (1) Rate
From MyTable
WHERE
    (ColA IS NULL OR ColA = @A) AND
    (ColB IS NULL OR ColB = @B) AND 
    (ColC IS NULL OR ColC = @C) AND 
    (ColD IS NULL OR ColD = @D)
ORDER BY
    (SELECT COUNT(n)
    FROM ( VALUES (ColA),(ColB),(ColC),(ColD) ) AS v(N) )
  DESC;
```

Comment: Thanks. But I fear this might get false matches - especially where the number of nulls are low and there are few real matches. I will try this out though.

Comment: No this will match any row where for each column: either it is null or it matches. We then order descending by how many non nulls there are. Need to add `SELECT TOP (1)` have edited